# Click Coordinates after Window Movement

Tags: c++, windows, click, mouse

Not being entirely familiar with programming GUIs in C++ and whatnot, I'm running into a problem where my program will not respond to a left-mouse click after moving/dragging the application window. What should I do to make it work properly? Here is how I am handling the left-click message in the callback function:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        POINT point;
        GetCursorPos(&point);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Post code that actually reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse location is included in the message as the LPARAM.

```
POINT point;
point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

As documented at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607.aspx), the point is relative to the upper left corner of the client area.  Therefore if you move the window, `point` will still be relative to your window.

[GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390.aspx) gets the position of the cursor in screen coordinates.  So you would have to compensate for the position of your window on the screen to get a usable position.